# Как экспортировать дату datetime?

Tags: python, excel, cx-oracle

Не могу экспортировать дату:

```
import xlwt
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
book = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet1 = book.add_sheet('sheet1')
cur.execute('SELECT date, name from table')
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row, array in enumerate(rows):
    for col, value in enumerate(array):
        sheet1.write(row, col, value)

name = "this.xls"
book.save(name)
book.save(TemporaryFile())
```

Вместо `17/08/2020` выдает `44044`, хотя `Name` выдает верный.

Comment: А что такое `book`?

Comment: @dIm0n здесь нашел https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068966/how-do-you-write-several-arrays-into-an-excel-file

Comment: Так там он определён, а у вас в коде — нет

Comment: @dIm0n добавил свой код, сорри не заметил, у меня тоже самое

Comment: @user357670, вы действительно хотите использовать устаревший Excel формат - `.xls` или это опечатка и вам нужен `.xlsx`?

Comment: @MaxU опечатка, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068966/how-do-you-write-several-arrays-into-an-excel-file просто копирнул. Самое странное добавляю xlsx файл не открывается)

Comment: @user357670, все правильно модуль `xlwt` умеет работать только с форматом .XLS. Если вам нужен формат `.XLSX`, то попробуйте использовать код из моего ответа

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем Pandas.

Пример:

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
from sqlalchemy import types, create_engine

#######################################################
### Oracle DB TNS description / connection string
#######################################################
tns = """
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = my-db-scan)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = my_service_name)
    )
  )
"""

usr = "test"
pwd = "my_oracle_password"

engine = create_engine(f'oracle+cx_oracle://{usr}:{pwd}@{tns}')

output_fn = r'/path/to/this.xlsx'
qry = 'SELECT date, name from table'
pd.read_sql(qry, engine).to_excel(output_fn, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
```

Comment: что часто используют pandas или xlrd? И какое по вашему мнению лучше?

Comment: @user357670, для обработки и анализа табличных данных - Pandas лучшее из доступного (при условии что данные вмещаются в память (RAM)). При работе с Excel файлами формата `.XLSX`, Pandas по умолчанию использует модуль `xlsxwriter`, но также поддерживает работу c можулями `openpyxl` и `xlrd` / `xlwt`

Comment: сорри @MaxU, как туда можно добавить переменную в qry?

Comment: @user357670, смотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1167150/211923)...

Answer (score 2):

> как можно добавить переменную в запрос (`qry`)?

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
from cx_Oracle import makedsn
from sqlalchemy import types, create_engine

usr = "test"
pwd = "my_oracle_password"
dsn = makedsn("ora_scan_or_hostname", 1521, service_name="my_service_name")

engine = create_engine(f'oracle+cx_oracle://{usr}:{pwd}@{dsn}')

output_fn = r'/path/to/this.xlsx'
qry = 'SELECT date, name from table where name = :name_var'
name = 'Joe'
pd.read_sql(qry, engine, params=(name, )).to_excel(output_fn, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
# NOTE: ---------------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: А зачем так сложно задаватъ параметры соединения (полответа tns)? Easy connect удобней же - `user/pass@my-db-scan/my_service_name`.

Comment: @0xdb, по двум причинам: 1.лень (использую код из предыдущих вопросов). 2. снова лень использовал код из рабочего скрипта, а на работе нужно было использовать `Load Balancing` в соединении, поэтому `easy connect` использовать было нельзя :)

Comment: А, если лень, то да, это веский аргумент :))

Comment: @0xdb, переделал по рекомендациям `SQL Alchemy`, `cx_Oracle` и `Pandas`. В Pandas ожидается использование прослойки `SQL Alchemy`, поэтому использовать объект `cx_Oracle.connection` не рекомендуется и не поддерживается.